# SQL query does not return the data in the columns

Tags: sql

I am trying to run a query to get all columns contained in the table if the table exist.

```
IF (EXISTS (SELECT *  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'2000064'))
```

The query gets executed but does not return anything! It just say "Query executed".

I have tried in several ways: TABLE_NAME = 2000064, TABLE_NAME = '2000064' but nothing is returned.
The table exists, and there are data in it.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

I need to return the data contained in the table if the table exists.

Comment: Do you mean your table name starts with number rather than character if not are you using object_id of table, if so...you have to search in sys.tables rather than information_schema.tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get information about the column, uou can just run:

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'2000064';
```

(Note:  you should include `TABLE_SCHEMA` as well to find a specific table.)

If the table does not exist, then you will get no rows back.  Putting it in an `if exists` statement, runs the query and would then run whatever is in the then clause.  Your question doesn't have the then part of the statement.

Comment: I see the point. Actually I need to return the data and not the information and only if the table exist. Could you please suggest how to get there?

Comment: @user3855329 . . . This question already has answers.  Ask another question, providing sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to do.  It is rude to invalidate answers by changing the question.